# Sorting output numbers without an array

Tags: c++, sorting

So the main task is to find all numbers divisible by 7 between 0 - 100 then sort them in descending order without using an array. I'm just starting c++ and one of my first lab tasks was this, however when I finished it I was told that I shouldn't have used an array. I'm now curious as to how to do so otherwise. The code here only finds the numbers divisible by 7 and naturally displays them in an ascending sort.

I'm unsure how I would sort them without storing the value in an array then changing switching the values that way.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

for( int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){

    if(i%7 == 0){

        //Display every integer divisible by 7
        cout << i << endl;

    }

}


return 0;

}
```

Comment: Instead of iterating from 0 to 100, why don't you go the other way?

Comment: just... for( int i = 100; i; i--) ?

Comment: Work backwards.  Start at 100, see if it is divisible, if it is print, move on to the next number towards 0.

Comment: When you say "sort" I'm guessing you actually mean "display?" Sort doesn't really have any meaning if you don't have a data structure that you're actually ordering things in.

Comment: Yeah just realised how simple this is...

Comment: Lets assume the question wants you to use `i` as counter that goes up in value. When you get your result, then you want to display in descending order. (Its kind of assumed the results will be in ascending order... but more impt. you don't trust your output to be descending unless you sort it yourself... well the question is: is sorting an array the best approach? (HINT: are there other data structures that are more sort-friendly?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reverse the for loop:

```
for( int i = 100; i >= 7; i--){ //There is no integer lower than 7 that is divisible by 7
    if(i%7 == 0){
        cout << i << endl;

    }    
}
```

Comment: Dangit, you beat me to it haha.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to find the lagest number divisible by 7 (here, 98) and just continue removing 7 to it until you run across the lowest boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop to go in descending order; then you won't have to sort anything.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is *start* at max and go down from there; as follows:

```
  for(int i = 100; i >= 0; i--){
    if(i % 7 == 0){
        cout << i << endl;
    }
  }
```

Comment: duplicate answer

Answer (score 0):

Bling it like its 2020 .. (You will get great grades ;-) )

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i=101;
    while(--i)i%7?cout:cout<<i<<endl;
}
```